# Pyspark write json value as string in csv column

Tags: python, json, csv, pyspark, databricks

I'm using **Databricks** and **Pyspark**.

I have a **notebook** that loads data from csv files into a **dataframe**.

```
dataframe = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true")\
                              .option("header", "true")\
                              .csv(csv_files)
```

The csv files can have columns that contains json values.

Example of csv file:

| Name | Age | Value | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 23 | 0 | 3 |
| Tom | 25 | 1 | 4 |
| Jeff | 25 | "{ ""property"" : ""value"",""property2"" : ""value2"" }" | 5 |

Then I apply some logic to the **dataframe** like agrupations and stuff like that.

Example of dataframe:

| Name | Age | Value | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 23 | 0 | 3 |
| Tom | 25 | 1 | 4 |
| Jeff | 25 | { ""property"" : ""value"",""property2"" : ""value2"" } | 5 |

And finally I save the dataframe into a csv file, let's say **newfile.csv**.

```
dataframe.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").option("escape",'"').csv(destination_folder)
```

The problem is that **newfile.csv** is like the below:

| Name | Age | Value | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 23 | 0 | 3 |
| Tom | 25 | 1 | 4 |
| Jeff | 25 | {""property":""value"" | ""property2"":""value2""} |

When we load a csv file as a dataframe,it gets rid of the double quotes, and that's why when we save that value it no longer contains double quotes.

Is taking the json commas as separators in the csv file. I tried using the option escape, but is not working.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I want to save json values as string values just like the first csv example.

Comment: the df you're writing has the fields as required?

Comment: @samkart I guess, I need all the fields. Or what exactly do you mean by required?

Comment: are the fields in the dataframe as you want them in your csv? i'm checking if the `value` field is correct in the dataframe

Comment: @samkart yes, the dataframe has the fields how I want them in my csv. In the dataframe the json value is in the proper column (Value). The problem appears when saving the dataframe into a csv

Answer (score 0):

Here, you would need to save your .csv file with a different separator than comma, since comma is separating the json into two different columns.
Here is how you can do it:

```
dataframe.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").option("sep", "|").csv(destination_folder)
```

Comment: The thing is that I want to keep the commas as separators, I want to keep that standard.

Comment: Then the only way is to replace the comma in the json with something else. Comma separated files, when read, will always separate by comma, which is one issue. There are only two options 1. To save with a different separator 2. To replace commas in the dataframe with another character

Comment: this'll still break as the json string will have a comma which the csv will use as a delimiter by default

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the quotes in your json, then quote the entire json in your csv. That is use \ to escape quotes instead of repeating the quotes.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Ok I played with it a bit and no need to escape with \. Simplest would be to just add extra quotes to your json in the original csv. e.g: `Alex,23,"""{""a"":""0"",""b"":""1""}""",val2 `